# How to select object by touch.view and isKindOfClass?

Tags: objective-c, class, object, touchesbegan

i've got simple if case in `touchesBegan` method:

```
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[Direction class]])
{
    //select tapped object and do something...
}
```

i've got on view many `Direction` objects, and when i tap on one i want to select it, like:

```
Direction *d = [touch.view].selectedObject; //something like that.
```

Can i do this in obj-C? or how can i do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[Direction class]])
{
    //do something...
    Direction *d = (Direction*)[touch view];
}
```

Comment: that was so simple ; ) Thank you